# Extract normalized/canonical directory name from path via Ruby stdlib?

Tags: ruby

Say you have a path String that can be one of:

- Foo/Bar/Baz.txt
- Foo/Bar/
- Foo/Bar

And in each case, you wish to isolate the directory hierarchy within the String, using methods in the Ruby standard library, resulting in the value `Foo/Bar`. Is there a single method that does this? Unfortunately, `Path#cleanpath` and other methods in the API preserve the trailing slash in the String.

Is there a single method or short method chain that behaves like the following?

`File.directory?(path) ? path.chomp("/") : File.split(path)[0]`

Another example of the desired behavior via a regex, is [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949088/what-regex-can-isolate-the-directory-hierarchy-from-a-path/26949494?noredirect=1#comment42440976_26949494).

Comment: I didn't get your actual question! :-)

Comment: I've added a snippet to illustrate the behavior. The question is clearly stated in sentences 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there does not seem to be a way to do this explicitly in the Ruby API. The alternative is to use a regex, [similar to what you see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949088/what-regex-can-isolate-the-directory-hierarchy-from-a-path/26949494).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understood your question, but if you want to split the directory and the file you could do like this:

```
path = "/etc/hosts" ; File.directory?(path) &&  [ File.dirname(path) + "/" +  
File.basename(path), nil ]  ||  [ File.dirname(path),  File.basename(path) ]
=> ["/etc", "hosts"]

path = "/var/lib" ; File.directory?(path) &&  [ File.dirname(path) + "/" +  
File.basename(path), nil ]  ||  [ File.dirname(path),  File.basename(path) ]
=> ["/var/lib", nil]
```

But note that this solutions applies only to the domain of existing files. If you are planning to create a path, it is impossible to know where `Bar` should be placed in the answer (in the above example, it will be considered a file).

Note that the answer is supposed to be normalized:

```
path = "//etc//hosts" ; File.directory?(path) &&  [ File.dirname(path) + "/" +  
File.basename(path), nil ]  ||  [ File.dirname(path),  File.basename(path) ]
=> ["/etc", "hosts"]
```

However the normalization of `dirname` is limited/buggy (in my opinion):

```
path = "/./etc//hosts" ; File.directory?(path) &&  [ File.dirname(path) + "/" 
+  File.basename(path), nil ]  ||  [ File.dirname(path),  File.basename(path) ]
=> ["/./etc", "hosts"]
```

Parsing is difficult and whenever possible to avoid it, you will certainly save time. Instead of normalizing file paths, I would rather trust their `inode` number (again, valid only for the domain of existing files):

```
[ File.stat("/etc/hosts").ino , File.stat("/./etc/hosts").ino ]
=> [1309513, 1309513]
```