# What regex can isolate the directory hierarchy from a path?

Tags: regex

Say you have a path that can be one of:

1. Foo/Bar/Baz.txt (a directory hierarchy followed by a file containing a single dot)
2. Foo/Bar/ (a directory hierarchy ending in a trailing slash)
3. Foo/Bar (a directory hierarchy that does not end with a trailing slash)

What's an effective regex to capture just the directory hierarchy from paths like these, resulting in capturing just `Foo/Bar` ?

Comment: In what language? [tag:JavaScript], [tag:php], [tag:python], [tag:perl]..?

Comment: Note that if `Foo/Bar` means directory `Bar` inside directory `Foo`, you won't bee able to have paths that point to files without extension.

Comment: You can't write a regex for these specs unless you distinguish what makes `Foo/Bar/Baz.txt` different than `Foo/Bar` or even `Fo.o/B.a.r`

Comment: I've clarified the constraints of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT:

```
^(.*?)(?:/(?:[^/.]*\.[^/.]+)?)?$
```

> [image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks, but then this doesn't answer the question, does it? :)

Comment: please add an example input what/how groups are matched.